# How to wait till ngIf inserts content in DOM?

Tags: angular

[Stackblitz Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mvp7n9)

```
    import { Component, Input,ViewChild,ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'hello',
  template: `<h1>Hello {{name}}!</h1>

  <button (click)='setFoo()'>Trigger NG IF</button>

  <div *ngIf="myFooBoolean" #fooDiv>
  myFooBoolean was set to true
  </div>
`,
  styles: [`h1 { font-family: Lato; }`]
})
export class HelloComponent {
  @Input() name: string;
  myFooBoolean: boolean;
  @ViewChild('fooDiv', {static: false}) fooDiv: ElementRef;

  setFoo() {
    this.myFooBoolean = true;
    const el: HTMLDivElement = this.fooDiv.nativeElement;
    console.log(el);
  }
}
```

If you click on the button you will see an  error in console because you are trying to access an Element that is being inserted into DOM by `Ngif` I can get past this error by using `setTimeout()`

But is there any other better way to go solve it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are two options I can think of:

1: Implement `ngAfterContentChecked()`
Wait until this is called by angular after each change detection (when your element is shown/hidden, and quite a few other things) in the dom.
Depending on your use case this might not be very usefull.

2: Inject a `ChangeDetectorRef` into your component, and after setting your `myFooBoolean` run `ChangeDetectorRef.detectChanges()`, and the line after that should be able to access your viewchild fine.

Comment: or try @ViewChild('fooDiv', {static: true}) fooDiv: ElementRef;

Answer (score 2):

try @ViewChild('fooDiv', {static: false}) fooDiv: ElementRef;